# Java For Loop with Array in columns

Tags: java

I want to make the code output the for loops into columns not just straight up and down in one column, but each int in each of the three for loops will make a column starting from left to right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        final int number_months = 12;
        int [] avgTemp = {46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 55, 51, 47};
        int [] avgRain = {5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4};
        int [] newGrowth;

        newGrowth = new int[number_months];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter minimum temperature for plant : ");
        int min_plant_temp = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter maximum temperature for plant : ");
        int max_plant_temp = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter minimum rainfall for plant : ");
        int min_rainfall_for_plant = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Month" + "   " + "Temp" + "   " + "Rain" + "  " + "Growth" + "  " + "Plant Height");
        for (int j=0; j<number_months; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);}
        for (int i = 0; i < avgTemp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(avgTemp[i]);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < avgRain.length; k++) {
            System.out.println(avgRain[k]);
        }
        {
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I want to make the above code print out the info in columns under month temp rain etc....but it outputs from top to bottom in a straight line instead of in columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println();
println() does print to the next line while print() will print it to the right instead of next line. 
And it should works like a magic.
Note: remember to add spaces so that each loops doesn't stack together.example System.out.print(j+" ");

Note: I think what you are trying to achieve is something like this

```
System.out.println("Month" + "   " + "Temp" + "   " + "Rain" + "  " + "Growth" + "  " + "Plant Height");
    for (int j=0; j<number_months; j++) {
        System.out.print(j+1 +" "); //since there is no 0 month. therefore you add 1 into j.
        System.out.print(avgTemp[j] + " ");
        System.out.print(avgRain[j] + " ");
        //System.out.print(newGrowth + " "); //after you determine what it is, this variable is not set yet.
        //System.out.print(plantHeight + " "); //after you determine what it is, this variable is not defined yet.
        System.out.println(); //after all rows are print, print this to set to the next line.
    }
```

Comment: it didnt work,  i just want to get under "Month" a column of numbers for number_months,  and then under "Temp"  the array of numbers for avgTemp and then for "Rain"  the array of numbers for avgRain ;  that is all I wanted to do for now.  Bijan

Comment: @Bjon123abc you need to specify that properly. I will update the codes in awhile.

Comment: This is the output I get when I copy and pasted your code,  yeah Im a piece of shi- I copied and pasted but I was trying to figure it out too :  Enter minimum temperature for plant : 1
Enter maximum temperature for plant : 1
Enter minimum rainfall for plant : 1
Month   Temp   Rain  Growth  Plant Height
1 46 5 [I@33909752 2 48 3 [I@33909752 3 49 3 [I@33909752 4 50 1 [I@33909752 5 51 1 [I@33909752 6 53 0 [I@33909752 7 54 0 [I@33909752 8 55 0 [I@33909752 9 56 0 [I@33909752 10 55 1 [I@33909752 11 51 3 [I@33909752 12 47 4 [I@33909752

Comment: @Bjon123abc do let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: Its okay iCezz,  you didnt get my question,  i dont want the user at this point to enter a month yet,  just have it output the columns with the info output beneath each column.  But thanks for trying to help me.  Bijan  PS : I mean the put the user input already,   but i am just concerned with the output of the for loops,  not the user input...

Comment: @Bjon123abc the previous code should input the column for each month. you have [i@sthsth] is because the variable is not set. you can just comment the part and it will works fine. I have updated it, you can try again.